# Operating on one list also changes the other

Tags: python, python-2.7

I solved Project Euler's Problem 67 a few months back with a wildly inefficient algorithm. Today, I realized how this could have been done better, and while trying to make a more efficient algorithm, I ran into some problems.

The code is this:

```
r_prev = [59,0,0]
r_load = [73,41,0]
r = [0,0,0]
zero_r = [0,0,0]
rows = 3
while rows != 0:
    position = 0
    for x in r_load:
        try:
            if r_prev[position] > r_prev[position-1]:
                r[position] = r_prev[position] + r_load[position]
            else:
                r[position] = r_prev[position-1] + r_load[position]
        except IndexError:
            r[position] = r_prev[position] + r_load[position]
        position += 1
    print r
    rows -= 1
    r_load = input("Enter next row")
    r_prev = r
    r_prev.append(0)
    zero_r.append(0)
    r = zero_r
```

It works by keeping only the sum of the highest path to get to a point. I am feeding it input manually at this point (via the console). When fed the first line, it performs as expect, but when fed the second line, it considers `r_prev` and `r` as the same thing, and every operation that is performed on `r_prev` is also performed on `r`.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `r_prev = r` you are not copying the list.  You are giving the same list an additional name.  To make a copy, do `r_prev = list(r)`.